# How do I approach new interview with same hiring manager?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, new-job

I interviewed for a position couple of months ago and didn't get an offer. I went through all the interview processes and at the end, I wasn't chosen. So couple of days ago I was contacted for a new position that opened up.

I already interviewed with that hiring manager who would be my boss. He knows my job history, experiences etc..What can I say/do so I don't sound like a broken clock? How should I approach this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What can I say/do so I don't sound like a broken clock? How should I
>   approach this?

It's a new job, a new interview, and hopefully a new ending.

Spend some time beforehand recalling what you said, the kinds of questions that were asked, and the kinds of answers you supplied. Look for ways to improve your answers and make them more powerful.

Think about and understand what makes this position different from the last. Be ready to emphasize your fit for *this* position and don't mention the *last* position unless the hiring manager brings it up.

Other than that, treat it just like an interview with a new hiring manager. Answer question fully and honestly. Give your best sales pitch.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you have been contacted again is because the hiring manager felt that though you were not a best fit for the position at that stage, you have potential. It might be that you were well liked but eventually they found a candidate somewhat better than you.

As a hiring manager, I also interview 4-5 candidates per job. Sometimes I like candidates, but eventually find a even better candidate. So I put the next best candidate on hold rather than reject, so that should another position open up, I can consider them or recommend them to other hiring managers.

My take would be to go for it, approach it like a new interview, but at the same time, as suggested in the other answer, consider what you have said before, what sort of questions came in, and if you need to brush up on something which you didn't answer well last time.

Most people would not have bothered to call you again if they had no intention of hiring you. Another possibility is that the HR is really bad and they have no record that you interviewed earlier with this hiring manager. In that case, a polite way of approaching would be to as the HR, I interviewed with you 2 months back, what is the time you would consider me again for a position? That may help you get some feedback. If its not in error, I am sure HR will get back to you to say, the hiring manager wants to talk to you again. In that case, lets say you have a very good chance to making it through this time. If not, they will ask you not to come for another round, which would mean saving time for both you and the organization.